# How to use Automapper toavoid foreach for complex structure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, mapping, automapper

I am trying to map source and destination instances using automapper,

I have a sample code which i have created . Line number 82 i am trying to change anduse automapper. Is it possible to use automapper there.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/bzp9H7

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can map a list, but after taking a look at your code I don't think you need a list or array for the `destinationArray` field. If you need to use it as an array, all you have to do is `adding.First()` after `destinationArray`:

```
  public static IMapper CreateGroboBookingMapper()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;

            cfg.CreateMap<Booking, DestinationBooking>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.processTypeField, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.processTypeField))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.travelDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Trip.Voyages.FirstOrDefault().DepartureDate))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.destinationArrayField, opt => opt.MapFrom(a => new destinationArray() 
            {
              // Here you can add destinationArray models parameters
            arrivalStationIdField= a.Trip.Voyages.Select(x => x.arrivalStationId).FirstOrDefault().ToString(),
            extraField = *************
        }));
       
        });

        return config.CreateMapper();
    }
```

And here is the result from debugging, as I've tried one value:

[image: Debugging Result]